# Make doesn't recompile after cleaning object files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following makefile:

```
compiler := g++
flags := -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror -O2 -march=native
libs := sqlite3

build_dir := build
debug_dir := debug
source_dir := src
object_dir := obj
include_dir := include

objects := main.o politician.o data_base.o exceptions.o input.o
# Prepend object_dir/ to every object
objects := $(patsubst %, $(object_dir)/%, $(objects))

dependencies := data_base.hpp exceptions.hpp politician.hpp input.hpp CLI11.hpp
# Prepend include_dir/ to every dependency
dependencies := $(patsubst %, $(include_dir)/%, $(dependencies))

executable := politician

# Don't remove object files when finished
.SECONDARY: $(objects)

.PHONY: all
all: $(build_dir)/$(executable) | $(build_dir)

.PHONY: debug
debug: flags += -g
debug: $(debug_dir)/$(executable) | $(debug_dir)/

%/$(executable): $(objects)
    $(compiler) $(flags) -l $(libs) $^ -o $@

$(object_dir)/%.o: $(source_dir)/%.cpp $(dependencies) | $(object_dir)/
    $(compiler) $(flags) -I $(include_dir) -c $< -o $@

%/:
    mkdir -p $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(objects)

.PHONY: clean-all
clean-all:
    rm -f $(objects) $(build_dir)/$(executable) $(debug_dir)/$(executable)
```

It's expected that, after running `make clean`, `make all` would recompile everything (because the executable depends on the objects and they are not present anymore), but it's not what's happening: instead I get `make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.`

What's causing this behavior?

Comment: It's hard to say.  Are you sure that the object files are actually gone?  You can run `make -d` to understand why make is deciding that nothing needs to be done.

Comment: @MadScientist I'm sure the object files in the obj directory are gone. `make -d` provides a LOT of information that I cannot understand, and `make --debug=basic` provides nothing useful, here's the output of the latter: https://i.imgur.com/CrcUhl6.png

Comment: [...] and here's the output of `make -d`: https://pastebin.com/b2ZHMQ2U

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you try removing a few elements of `objects`, and seeing if the error persists? This is a first step to a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Beta Thanks! I appreciate the link as I didn't knew of these tips. As for your suggestion, manually removing any objects produces the same output. The only thing that triggers a recompilation is removing the binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are using a chain of pattern rules.

Consider a simple example:

```
all: build/politician

build/politician: main.o
    whatever...

main.o: src/main.cpp
    whatever...
```

If you run `make`, it will build `main.o`, then `build/politician`. If you then delete `main.o` and again run `make`, again it will build `main.o` and `build/politician`.

Now change two of the rules into pattern rules:

```
all: build/politician

%/politician: main.o
    whatever...

%.o: src/%.cpp
    whatever...
```

Now the first time you run `make`, it will once again build `main.o` and then `build/politician`. But then when you delete `main.o` and again run `make`, it will report "Nothing to be done for 'all'" and do nothing. This is because `main.o` is now an **intermediate file**, and according to [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules):

> If an ordinary file b does not exist, and make considers a target that depends on b, it invariably creates b and then updates the target from b. But if b is an intermediate file, then make can leave well enough alone. It won’t bother updating b, or the ultimate target, unless some prerequisite of b is newer than that target or there is some other reason to update that target.

Comment: Ah tricky.  I was confused because `$(objects)` does appear in the prerequisite list and that's normally enough to keep a target from being considered intermediate.  However I realized that this target is a pattern rule, which is unusual.  Usually an executable is an explicit rule like `$(build_dir)/$(executable): $(objects)` but because an implicit rule is used instead `%/$(executable): $(objects)`, `$(objects)` here are not considered "mentioned" in the makefile.

Comment: There's no point to this being a pattern rule.  If you simply change the pattern rule `%/$(executable): $(objects)` to an explicit rule `$(build_dir)/$(executable): $(objects)` then it will all work as you expect.

Comment: @MadScientist the reason I used `%/$(executable)` was because the debug executable is being compiled on a different directory, $(debug_dir), so this pattern rule allowed me to reference both the build and the debug executables. Anyway, I was going to ask this same question regarding the objects being intermediate, thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: Actually, changing this rule to `$(build_dir)/$(executable): $(objects)` didn't work. Now I'm confused...

Comment: Just found the problem: I forgot to remove the `.SECONDARY: $(objects)`, now it's working as expected.

Comment: I recommend always avoiding the use of `.SECONDARY`.  It's very tricky to use, has unexpected side-effects, and it's trivial to ensure files are not considered intermediate in the first place: just make some rule, any rule, that lists your files as prerequisites.  Even something silly like `make-objs: $(objects)`  Voila!  Not intermediate.

Comment: IMO it's very dangerous to put executables in a different directory for debug, but leave the object files in the same directory.  That can easily lead to some unknown cross-section of files compiled with debug vs. optimized, depending on which files have been changed last and whether you've remembered to always run `make` vs. `make debug` etc.  If you want to allow both types of builds it's better to put _both_ the object files and executable in separate directories.